# How to make full row button?

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

Please help me to make a full row button like on the picture.I want that when I click on any place on the row and it was like a button.
I have 2 images and Label.Please help
[image]

Comment: Can you please include sample XAML?

Comment: You can define the column definition of Grid to achieve it.

Comment: 1)sorry but I do not understand how to write it.so I can not give an example

Comment: 2)if i write it in the grid. Will the button work when I click on the image in another column?I think that no.If I do not understand right.please say

Comment: Please share your xaml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many different solutions which can implement it . For example you could use the following code .

#### in xaml

```
<StackLayout>

        <StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>

            <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="TapGestureRecognizer_Tapped"  />

        </StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>

        <Grid  BackgroundColor="White" HorizontalOptions="Fill" VerticalOptions="Fill" RowSpacing="0" ColumnSpacing="0">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="40" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                <ColumnDefinition Width="0.2*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="0.6*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="0.2*" />

            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <Image Grid.Column="0" Source="icon.png" />
            <Label Grid.Column="1" Text="Map Settings" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" FontSize="20" />
            <Image Grid.Column="2" Source="arrow.png" />


        </Grid>
    </StackLayout>
```

#### in code behind

```
private void TapGestureRecognizer_Tapped(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   DisplayAlert("Title","Clicked !!","OK");
}
```

[image]